# How can I have an app in portrait mode with only one DialogFragment that can change orientation?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have an application with one `Activity` and some `Fragments` in it. I want my app in portrait mode, but there is one `DialogFragment` that must detect orientation, and changes its layout accordingly.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

in its `onCreate` you should set programmatically its orientation to `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED`

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: If I call getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED); in my Fragment's onCreate, it will set the orientation of the Activity, not the Fragment, right?

Comment: yes id does. You can force the orientation to landscape in onPause e to unspecified inside the onResume

Comment: But then, how can I set the orientation for my Fragments, i.e. all in portrait, except one that can change orientation?

Comment: I think you can't. Do you have a multiple panel app?